# Timer built in javascript resets when page is refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I am having a problem on storing my timer in a localStorage. Everytime I refresh the browser, the timer resets. Now what I want to do is to store my timer in a localStorage so everytime the user refreshes the browser the timer wont reset. Please check my code below

HTML

```
<p class="w3-xlarge w3-serif"> <i>Linguistics Exam</i><span class="w3-right" id="timeLeft" name="timeLeft"></span></p>
```

JS

```
var total_seconds = 40*60;
var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);

function checkTime(){
    document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = 'Time Left: ' + c_minutes + ' : ' + c_seconds;

    if(total_seconds <= 0 ){
        $(document).ready(function(){$("#submitLinguistics").click();});

    }else{
        total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
        c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
        c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
        setTimeout("checkTime()", 1000);
    }
}
setTimeout("checkTime()", 1000);
```

Comment: where is your code to save it to `localStorage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change `setTimeout` to `setInterval`, which will be executed upon each second instead of manually calling `setTimeout` on each instance:

```
var total_seconds = 40*60;
var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);

function checkTime(){
document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = 'Time Left: ' + c_minutes + ' : ' + c_seconds;

if(total_seconds <= 0 ){
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#submitLinguistics").click();});
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}else{
    total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
    c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
    c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
}
}
var myInterval = setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
```

Next, you need to write `total_seconds` into the `localStorage`:

```
var total_seconds = localStorage.getItem("total_seconds") ? localStorage.getItem("total_seconds") : 40*60;
var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);

function checkTime(){
document.getElementById("timeLeft").innerHTML = 'Time Left: ' + c_minutes + ' : ' + c_seconds;

if(total_seconds <= 0 ){
    $(document).ready(function(){$("#submitLinguistics").click();});
    clearInterval(myInterval);
}else{
    total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
    c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
    c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
}
localStorage.setItem("total_seconds", total_seconds);
}
var myInterval = setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
```

Finally, if you close the tab and reopen it after a while, the counter will reload from where it was and the user could cheat by closing the tab, working on the answer and opening it again. To cope with this situation, it is recommendable to cooperate with the server, that is, working with an actual date and loading based on that instead of using `localStorage`. A programmer user might even reset the timer from the console in the dev tools.

Comment: Thank you sir Lajos. It worked for me. But i got a problem giving different timer to every user. I searched for it and  used sessionStorage instead. Unfortnately, using sessionStorage does not also resets the timer even it's for another user. Any solution for this without cooperating with the server? Thank you sir

Comment: @AngeloSaño you could use localStorage.getItem("total_seconds" + theusername) and localStorage.setItem("total_seconds" + theusername, total_seconds); to achieve that. However, if the different users are using different browsers, then their localStorage will be different. localStorage is the browser's local storage and it is different for each browser. If my answer helped you solve the problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct one.

Comment: Thank you sir Lajos! Sorry for not accepting it right away im newbie here but it is true that it helped me solved my problem.

Comment: @AngeloSaño no problem at all, we needed to reach to the point when we could be sure that this answer solves the problem indeed.